# GreaseMonkey - JavaScript - Remove some css and js refs suffixes

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, replace

I have css and js links in head AND body from a website where i want to remove a suffix.

The CSS link in the head looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/some.css?r=5.6" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/someother.css?r=5.6" media="screen" />
```

and some JavaScript includings in the body like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/some.js?r=5.6"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/someother.js?r=5.6"></script>
```

Now i want to remove the "?r=5.6" part from this links (with GreaseMonkey).

With the following code i find it and can use it to make - for example - an alert():

```
var cssLinks=document.getElementsByTagName("link");

for (var i=0;i<cssLinks.length;i++)
{
    alert(cssLinks[i].href.replace(/\?r=5.6/, ""));
}

var scriptLinks=document.getElementsByTagName("script");

for (var i=0;i<scriptLinks.length;i++)
{
    alert(scriptLinks[i].src.replace(/\?v=2.2.7/, ""));
}
```

But i want replace it in the source, so that the ?r=5.6 isn't parsed. I tried many examples with document.innerHTML, xPath and others but i can't find the right solution.

Can you help? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important points:**

1. Ordinarily, when you replace a query parameter, like that.  EG:

   ```
   http://example.com/someother.css?r=5.6
   ```

   To:

   ```
   http://example.com/someother.css
   ```

   It will have no effect.  The `?r=5.6` is just a trick to get the browser to get the latest version of the file (not cached), without having to actually rename the file itself.
2. The good news is, that if you actually change the CSS file, EG:

   ```
   http://example.com/File_1.css
   ```

   To:

   ```
   http://example.com/File_2.css
   ```

   Then the CSS rules will be replaced, in Firefox, like you would hope.
3. **BUT**, if you actually change the JS file, EG:

   ```
   http://example.com/File_A.js
   ```

   To:

   ```
   http://example.com/File_B.js
   ```

   Then **the new JS is not executed** at all!  The old JS is still in memory, to boot.
4. So, you can add the new JS like so:

   ```
   function addJS_Node (text, s_URL) {
       var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
       scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";
       if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
       if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

       var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.body || d.documentElement;
       targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
   }

   addJS_Node (null, "http://example.com/File_B.js");
   ```

   But, that might cause interesting effects if both files (`File_A.js` and `File_B.js`) use/set the same timers or event listeners.

   Possible workaround: Use something like [AdBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) to stop `File_A.js` from loading.

Anyway, here's a complete Greasemonkey script that does what you *asked*.
See the notes, above, about how and what will actually work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Swap CSS and Javascript links.
// @include         http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var targCSS = $("link[rel=stylesheet][href*='r=5.6']");

targCSS.each ( function () {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    jThis.attr ('href', jThis.attr ('href').replace (/\?r=5.6/i, '') );
} );

var targJS  = $("script[src*='v=2.2.7']");

/* No workie.  That is, new script will not execute.
targJS.each ( function () {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    jThis.attr ('src', jThis.attr ('src').replace (/\?v=2.2.7/i, '') );
} );
*/
targJS.each ( function () {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    var newSrc  = jThis.attr ('src').replace (/\?v=2.2.7/i, '')

    addJS_Node (null, newSrc);
} );

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL) {
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";
    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;
    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.body || d.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: also a big thy for your great explanations